# What ports should I open for Firebase cloud messaging in my rails server?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

What I'm trying to do:
HTTP messaging to my android app

Rails server on AWS -> HTTP request to Firebase with fcm gem -> HTTP Response

In this flow, what port should I open to Firebase server?

I've opened 5228~5230 as FCM docs said, but it didn't work.
(My server retunrs 500, execution expired error)
Only when I open all ports open to whole world, it worked.

What ports should I open..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

5228~5230 ports are used to receive messages.

To send messages you only need to be able to open connections to

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

Depending on your configuration this might not require any change (usually connections open from the server don't require firewall changes) or it might require to open the standard `HTTPS` port: **443**